# Media Player audio when button clicked android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a situation that when i press a image button it highlights (color filter) and plays its audio. I have 2 alphabets in one image and have audio of both alphabets in 1 .mp3 file. Ultimately i need when image button clicked audio plays one by one with respective alphabet highlighted and audio on one click. anyone here to help me with this.

```
case R.id.pg2_4: {

            clearcolor();
            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
                clearcolor();
            }
            try {
                pg2_4.setColorFilter(0xff00ff00, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN);
                mp.reset();
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;

                if (Settings.GetPreferencesInteger("audio", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 0) {
                    afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q1p2_1.mp3");
                } else if (Settings.GetPreferencesInteger("audio", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 1) {
                    afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q2p2_1.mp3");
                } else if (Settings.GetPreferencesInteger("audio", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 2) {
                    afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q3p2_1.mp3");
                } else if (Settings.GetPreferencesInteger("audio", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 3) {
                    afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q4p2_1.mp3");
                }
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    clearcolor();
                }
            });
            break ;
        }
        case R.id.pg2_5: {

            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
                clearcolor();
            }
            try {
                pg2_5.setColorFilter(0xff00ff00, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN);
                mp.reset();
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;

                if (Settings.GetPreferencesInteger("audio", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 0) {
                    afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q1p2_2.mp3");
                } else if (Settings.GetPreferencesInteger("audio", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 1) {
                    afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q2p2_2.mp3");
                } else if (Settings.GetPreferencesInteger("audio", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 2) {
                    afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q3p2_2.mp3");
                } else if (Settings.GetPreferencesInteger("audio", getActivity().getApplicationContext()) == 3) {
                    afd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("q4p2_2.mp3");
                }
                mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    clearcolor();
                }
            });
            break ;
        }
```

this is onclick code

Comment: Where is you code buddy?

Comment: @AkshayMukadam i edited it